# Can't see link unless you hover over link?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm having an issue on my site http://noahsdad.com; if you look at the widget I installed at the very bottom, you can't see the links unless you hover over them. This doesn't just happen with this widget, almost any I put in have a 'haze' over them, if that makes sense.

I'm wondering if someone could help me figure out what's going on, and how to correct it.

Thanks.

Comment: Just change the color of your link, it's visible but not visible for the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links are visible, they are just set to a light grey colour. You have these rules defined in your default.css file:

```
a:link, a:visited {
  color: #EEEEEE;
}

a:hover {
  color: #999999;
}
```

You could change the value of the standard link colour, or you create a new rule with a higher specitivity, so that only links in that widget are affected.

```
#dsq-combo-widget a {
  color: #999;
}
```

**Update**

You haven't specified the color for your new style:

```
.widget ul li a:link, .widget ul li a:visited {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  #999;  <-- Add this
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added that but the links are still showing the same. What did I do wrong? (Thanks for your help by the way.)

Comment: Hmm...so strange. I've put that in my custom CSS file. I just double checked. I don't think I can put a screen shot here, but it's there.... Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Only because of color you can't see it but it's visible. You have a predefined color (#EEE) for all of your "a:link, a:visited" at  "http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/ProPhoto_10/style.css" at line 3 and all links are inheriting that color so if you want to change the color for your widgets then add another color like

```
.widget ul li a:link, .widget ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333; /*or whatever you want*/
}
```

It's at line 345 in the same file.